# Asp.net view not call controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have view Home

Here is code of it

```
   @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>

</div>


<div style="width: 100%; margin-top: 60px;">
    <div style="width: 65%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <form id="form" style="text-align: center;" asp-action="ShortenUrl" method="post">
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter Url ..."
                style="width: 100%; border-radius: 5px; height: 45px;"
                name="longUrl"/>

            <button
                style="background-color: darkgreen; color: white; padding: 10px; margin-top: 25px; border-radius: 8px;"
                type="submit">
                Shorten Url
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IShortLinkAppService _shortLinkAppService;

    public HomeController(IShortLinkAppService shortLinkAppService)
    {
        _shortLinkAppService = shortLinkAppService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string input)
    {
        var shortLink = await _shortLinkAppService.Redirect(input);

        if (shortLink == null)
        {
            return View();
        }

        return Redirect(shortLink.OriginalUrl);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ShortenUrl(string longUrl)
    {
        var shortLink = await _shortLinkAppService.GenerateShortUrl(longUrl);

        return View(shortLink);
    }
}
```

When I click button submit, nothing happens, breakpoint at  `var shortLink = await _shortLinkAppService.GenerateShortUrl(longUrl);` not hitting

Here is startup config

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("UrlShortenerApi.EntityFrameworkCore")));


        //Mapper
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MappingsProfile>());
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));


        services.Scan(scan =>
            scan.FromAssemblyOf<IShortLinkAppService>()
                .AddClasses()
                .AsMatchingInterface());

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

How I ca fix this issue?

Comment: Your form is missing `asp-controller="Home"`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: With `<form id="form" style="text-align: center;" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ShortenUrl" method="post">` same stuff @HastaTamang

Comment: Could you check if you have tag helpers in your scope? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

try to replace form by Html.BeginForm and add model

```
@model ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("ShortenUrl", "Home", FormMethod.Post) {

<input asp-for="LongUrl" class="form-control" style="text-align: center;" />

}
```

and since you are using mvc you need a model too

```
public class ViewModel
{
public string LongUrl get; set;
}
```

and actions

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     var model =  new ViewModel();
        return View(model);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> ShortenUrl(ViewModel model)
{
var longUrl=model.LongUrl;

....your code
}
```

Comment: And left all other code like it is?

Comment: Try this, for the start. But I think you need to add model too

Comment: Yes, that calls controller

Comment: Ok , now add model, see my updated answer

Comment: As I see it's working great without model

Hus t with `@using (Html.BeginForm("ShortenUrl", "Home", FormMethod.Post) {}`

Comment: Yes,you don't need to add a model,because asp .net core bind data with name attribute by default.